# задачка из учебника learn.javascript.ru на тему insertBefore и appendChild

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию insertAfter(elem, refElem), которая добавит elem после узла refElem. 
как я понимаю нужно вставить elem после первого дива на странице(между двух дивов).
но у меня даже с решением которое дают в учебнике, не получается это сделать. спасибо тем, кто потратит на меня время

```
<div>Это</div>
<div>Элементы</div>

<script>
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = '<b>Новый элемент</b>';

  function insertAfter(elem, refElem) { /* ваш код */ }

  var body = document.body;

  // вставить elem после первого элемента
  insertAfter(elem, body.firstChild); // <--- должно работать
```

Comment: ну так ты должен был написать свой код вместо комментария `/* ваш код */`

Comment: там же даже решение есть...

Comment: я копировал то решение, но у меня не работает оно..

Comment: и вместо комментариев тоже подставлял..

Comment: @ЕвгенийФёдоров, а почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что firstChild выбирает первый элемент из childNodes, а childNodes возвращает массив состоящий не только из дочерних "теговых" элементов, но и из текстовых. Т.к. сразу после body у нас в html как правило стоит знак переноса строки ("enter"), то и firstChild возвращает #text c nodeValue "↵  ".

Можно использовать node.children[0] чтобы выбрать первый "теговый" элемент и все должно заработать.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>Это</div>
    <div>Элементы</div>
</body>
<script>
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = '<b>Новый элемент</b>';

    function insertAfter(elem, refElem) {
        refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
    }

    var body = document.body;

    insertAfter(elem, body.children[0]); //почти как firstChild
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Да спасибо, так работает . но тут суть вопроса в том, чтоб написать функцию не меняя ничего в коде.. есть варианты как с делать с firstChild ?

Answer (score 0):

Если так важно использовать firstChild, то можно добавить цикл, который будет считать refElem'ом первый "теговый" элемент

```
function insertAfter(elem, refElem) {
    console.log(refElem.nodeName);

    while (refElem.nodeName == "#text") {//перебирать все элементы сначала до тегового элемента
        refElem = refElem.nextSibling;
    }

    refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: цикл не нужен, потому что вставлять нужно после переданного элемента. И даже если ты хотел найти следующий элемент, есть [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)